# Pandas Pyplot Multiple Markers, same line

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have a df:

```
time    c_1    c_2   c_3
 t1      v1    NaN    t1
 t2      v2    NaN    NaN   
 t3      v3    t3     NaN 
 t4      v4    NaN    NaN 
 t5      v5    t5     NaN 
 t6      v6    NaN    t6
```

How do you:

1. Use matplotlib.pyplot to plot a line (t1, c_1)
2. And marks every corresponding point in (c_2) on the line in a particular style (say, green)
3. And also mark every point in (c_3) on the same line in another style (say, blue)
4. Then draw a dotted line to connect the markers (t1, t3), t3, t6) and (t5, t6)

I broke the questions down into points so that it is easier to read, but essentially I'm very new to pyplot, and I can't find a way to style 2 different markers in the same syntax. I'm also not very sure how to manipulate the markers, if that even possible..

What is the 'usual' way to accomplish this?

Comment: @splinter, many questions seems unclear to you on stackoverflow. It should be evident that **t1 under column Time represents a time (i.e. datetime, not string)**, and `plt.plot(df['c_1'])` is a valid operation that plots values against time. If not, a constructive suggestion to perform `df.reset_index()` would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have this dataframe:

```
        c_1  c_2  c_3  time
0  0.548814  NaN  1.0     1
1  0.715189  NaN  NaN     2
2  0.602763  3.0  NaN     3
3  0.544883  NaN  NaN     4
4  0.423655  5.0  NaN     5
5  0.645894  NaN  6.0     6
```

If the following plot is what you're after

[image]

it can be produced with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)

time = np.arange(1,7)
c_1 = np.random.rand(6)
c_2 = time*np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan])
c_3 = time*np.array([1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1])

df = pd.DataFrame({"time":time, "c_1":c_1,"c_2":c_2,"c_3":c_3 })

ax = df.plot("time", "c_1")
ax.plot(df["c_2"], df["c_1"], marker="s", color="limegreen",  linestyle="")
ax.plot(df["c_3"], df["c_1"], marker="o", color="crimson", linestyle="")

# to be able to draw a line with coordinates 
# from two different columns, we need to join them
df2 = df[["c_1","c_2"]].dropna()
df3 = df[["c_1","c_3"]].dropna().rename(columns = {'c_3':'c_2'}, inplace = False)
df4 = pd.concat([df2, df3]).sort_values(by=["c_2"])

ax.plot(df4["c_2"], df4["c_1"], color="burlywood",  linestyle=":", lw=2.5)

ax.set_xlim(0,7)
plt.show()
```

Comment: is there a reason to reset the df index away from a datetime index? If I want to display the datetime on the plot, am I right to plot (time, value) and pass a valid (time, value) coordinate marker and it would achieve the same result as above?

Comment: I did not reset anything away from anything else. Since you did not share any actual dataframe I needed to invent one.

Comment: Oh okay. I understand the technique now. Thanks for sharing!